# How to get Selected value for list in Actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, list, components

I create a list Companents in as3, and I added item using `list.addItem({label:  "Topman"});`
while i get the value of Selected list `trace(list.selectedItem);`

> it returns [object Object].

How can I solve this problem? Anybody help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if ( list.selectedItem != null && list.selectedItem.hasOwnProperty("label") ) {
    trace( "Selected label is: " + list.selectedItem.label );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the label using `list.selectedItem.label`

Comment: I tried the above coding,i got Error like this TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: Then the list was not fully initialized or there was no selection. Wait for one frame before accessing the list's properties.